# VBA - help needed to calculate in between two worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA beginner and startet to work with it two weeks ago.
Right now I want to do a simple calculation how a price compared to an older state has developed (in percent). So I have two price papers in different worksheets and want to calculate whether the new price is higher or lower. The result is shown next to the "newColumn" in the worksheet "PricePaper1".
This has to work in a loop. Therefore I can't use the macro recorder function.

My idea is this but it doesn't work:

```
Dim newColumn As Integer
Dim oldColumn As Integer 
Dim oldRow As Integer 

newColumn = 7
oldColumn = 9
oldRow    = 11
newRow    = 11

For i to 25
Worksheets("PricePaper1").Cells(i, 8).Value =
1 - Worksheets("PricePaper1").Cells(oldRow, oldColumn).Value / Worksheets("PricePaper2").Cells(newRow, newColumn).Value
Next
```

Thanks in advance!!
Julius

Comment: **1.** When working with rows, it is advisable to declare them as `Long` instead of `Integer` **2.** `For i to 25` should be `For i = 1 to 25`. You may want to read up on [For...Next statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) **3.** You also have to increment the other variables else it will always refer to the same cell. **4.** I have a feeling that whatever you are trying to achieve can be done with formulas and no VBA is required here.

Comment: `Dim newColumn As long 
Dim oldColumn As long  
Dim oldRow As long  
newColumn = 7 
oldColumn = 9 
oldRow    = 11 
newRow    = 11  
For i = 1 to 25 
Worksheets("PricePaper1").Cells(i, 8).Value = 1 - Worksheets("PricePaper1").Cells(oldRow, oldColumn).Value / Worksheets("PricePaper2").Cells(newRow, newColumn).Value 
oldRow = oldRow + 1 
newRow = newRow +1 
Next`

I think you are right with your guess that this might be easier with formulas but I would really like to be able to find a VBA solution. 

Thanks for your fast answer @SiddharthRout

Comment: @SiddharthRout this is a piece of advice I never came across before, why Long instead of integer for rows? Should it be for columns as well? Perhaps I've been doing this wrong for ages...

Comment: @SpencerBarnes the maximum possible number of rows is bigger than what `Integer` can hold and so it can cause overflow error if your row count happens to exceed that. You also have almost no reason to declare `Integer` in VBA nowadays as VBA deals `Integer` as if it is `Long` internally so you might as well just declare `Long` from the start. The maximum number of column doesn't exceed `Integer` max size but again, no reason to declare it as `Integer`.

Comment: If you have a formula ready then you do not even need a loop ;) You can enter the formula in the entire range in 1 go! and then change them to values in the end.

Comment: But do you know what my mistake is in the calculation above? 
Your help is appreciated!

Comment: `Cells(oldRow, oldColumn)` and `Cells(newRow, newColumn)` do not make use of `i` to iterate the address. As the loop progresses, those two cells will not move, meaning the whole loop will just use the same values for every calculation. `oldRow = oldRow + 1` is an idea, but a better idea is to just do `Cells(oldRow + i - 1, oldColumn)`